# Bridge multiple LAN ports to a WAN

Tags: local-area-network, bridge, wide-area-network

I have a network device which has 1 WAN port and 4 LAN ports.

This device is running linux under the hood.

I want to connect the WAN port to the 'wider network' which supplies DHCP and connect devices to the LAN ports 'transparently' so they each receive an IP from DHCP and can directly reach/be reached by other devices on the network (without adding a NAT layer and needing firewalls to be managed).

What is the best solution to this problem?

Can I bridge each of the LAN ports individually to the WAN port (with `brctl` for example)?

I know this is possible directly where there is only 1 LAN/1 WAN port (as I have done it before), but is it also possible with multiple LAN ports?

Is this even the best solution to this problem?

If not, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `brctl addif br0 ethN` to add all the ethernet ports to the bridge along with the WAN port. Your interface identifiers may vary.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want to separate your LAN ports from each other, you could bridge them all together. A bridge is perfectly capable of connecting multiple devices.